# java project that counts votes java beginner

Tags: java

When I compile this I receive the errors

> Error: Syntax error on token "else", { expected
>   Error: Syntax error on token ")", EmptyStatement expected after this token

How do I fix these errors, and will this fix the program?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Election
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    int votesForPolly;  // number of votes for Polly in each precinct
    int votesForErnest; // number of votes for Ernest in each precinct
    int totalPolly;     // running total of votes for Polly
    int totalErnest;    // running total of votes for Ernest
    String response;    // answer (y or n) to the "more precincts" question

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println ();
    System.out.println ("Election Day Vote Counting Program");
    System.out.println ();
    // Initializations

    // Loop to "process" the votes in each precinct
    {System.out.println ("Enter Votes? Enter Y or N");
    response=scan.next().toUpperCase();

    if (response.equals("Y"))
      response="Yes"; 

    System.out.println ("Enter votes for Polly:");
    votesForPolly=scan.nextInt();
    totalPolly=totalPolly+ votesForPolly;
    System.out.println ("Enter votes for Ernest:");
    votesForErnest=scan.nextInt();
    totalErnest=totalErnest+ votesForErnest;}
    System.out.println ("Enter another District? Enter Y or N");
    response=scan.next().toUpperCase(); }

    else
    {
      response = 0;
      while (response == 1) 
    }

    // Print out the results
    System.out.println ("Total votes for Polly is: " + totalPolly);
    System.out.println ("Total votes for Ernest is: " + totalErnest); 
  }
}
```

Comment: There aren't many ways to interpret `syntax error`. Format your code and check your `{` and `}`.

Comment: Use IDE and Code Formatting :) This is much easier when code looks nice.

Comment: @MariuszS Code Formatting won't work if there are missing `}` or `{`. But it will help to match pairs of `{` and `}`.

Comment: Hmm, in IntelliJ this helps me spot missing braces...

Comment: if the errors are all due to braces then what does emptystatement error mean and what is the syntax error on else

Comment: There is `else` without `if`!

Comment: There is also `while` without `do`.

Comment: SO if Response is "NO"  What do you want your program to do? IN THAT CASE

Answer (score 1):

This code looks like this

```
public class Election {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        { 
           if (response.equals("Y"))  // if START
                response="Yes";       // if END 
        }

    } else { // else without if 

        while (response == 1) // while without do

    }  // main() END

} // class END

} // ???
```

There is missing openning brace, `else` without `if` and `while` without `do`.

Your `if` is equivalent to

```
if (response.equals("Y")) {
    response="Yes"; 
}
```

This is one liner `if` without `else`.

Comment: thanks I fixed the missing opening brace, but I don't know what you mean by else without if.  I have an if statement on the 21st line.

Comment: `if` from 21st line is closed on 22st line, `if` without braces is one liner.

Answer (score 1):

Here is code that compiles, but you have a few major problems in your code, I will try to point a few of them out below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Election {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int votesForPolly = 0;  // number of votes for Polly in each precinct
        int votesForErnest = 0; // number of votes for Ernest in each precinct
        int totalPolly = 0;     // running total of votes for Polly
        int totalErnest = 0;    // running total of votes for Ernest
        String response = "";    // answer (y or n) to the "more precincts" question

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Election Day Vote Counting Program");
        System.out.println();
        // Initializations

        // Loop to "process" the votes in each precinct
        System.out.println("Enter Votes? Enter Y or N");
        response=scan.next().toUpperCase();

        if (response.equals("Y")) {
            response="Yes"; 
            System.out.println("Enter votes for Polly:");
            votesForPolly=scan.nextInt();
            totalPolly=totalPolly + votesForPolly;
            System.out.println ("Enter votes for Ernest:");
            votesForErnest=scan.nextInt();
            totalErnest=totalErnest + votesForErnest;
            System.out.println("Enter another District? Enter Y or N");
            response=scan.next().toUpperCase(); 
        } else {
            // int count = 0; <--- see below 
            // while (count == 1) { <--- makes no sense in your context
                // Print out the results
                System.out.println("Total votes for Polly is: " + totalPolly);
                System.out.println("Total votes for Ernest is: " + totalErnest); 
            // }
        }
    }
}
```

1. First a few of your variables get never initialized. The compiler will complain about that fact.
2. You missed a lot of braces through your code.
3. Your `while` statement at the end will never executed because the condition is always false, respective it will never get `1`. In your context it seems like this `while` loop is completely unnecessary, because you only want to print a single vote count.
4. Also I renamed your condition variable there, because you can not assign the same variable name to more then one variable, also you can not change the type, without to declare this.
5. This `response="Yes";` makes not much sense in this context.

Comment: I made your corrections and now the program just ends when I try to enter another district, and it also does not print out the total votes for polly and ernest.  How can I fix this?  The while loop was meant to start the voting over again for another district, and the program was supposed to print out the final number of votes

Comment: @user3188303, SO is not the place to do your homework for you, because it defeats the purpose of assigning homework in the first place. If you want it to loop, insert a loop in the correct place (near the comment)

Comment: It ends because of your `if` / `else` statement. If your response is *Y* the `if` part will entered, not the `else` part.  
Just put `System.out.println("Total votes for Polly is: " + totalPolly);
System.out.println("Total votes for Ernest is: " + totalErnest); `below the `else` brace.
But you should learn this basics, I don't see your effort if I code this minor problems for you. No offense.

Comment: I did the homework, I just had trouble figuring out the errors I recieved